# No ideals coprime in DVR?

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, dedekind-domain

There's this exercise in Neukirch, chapter I, §3 (i've changed the statement to deal only with the case that bothers me):

Let $\mathfrak o$ be a Dedekind domain and $\mathfrak m$ be a nonzero integral ideal of $\mathfrak o$. Prove that there exists an integral ideal $\mathfrak a$ of $\mathfrak o$ that belongs to the same class of $\mathfrak m$ (in the classes of the ideal class group) and that is relatively prime to $\mathfrak m$.

But there's this case I cannot deal with: let $\mathfrak o$ have only finitely many prime ideals and let $\mathfrak m$ be the product of all those prime ideals. Is there even an integral ideal of $\mathfrak o$ coprime to $\mathfrak m$? Thank you.

EDIT: for completeness, I add the unchanged statement of the exercise:

"**Exercise 8.** Let $\mathfrak m$ be a nonzero integral ideal of the Dedekind domain $\mathfrak o$. Show that in every ideal class of $Cl_K$, there exists an integral ideal prime to $\mathfrak m$."

Comment: When $\mathfrak o$ has only finitely many prime ideals its ideal class group is trivial, so take $\mathfrak a = \mathfrak o .$

Answer (score 2):

You're right, there's no such ideal, since an ideal $\neq\mathfrak o$ is contained in a maximal ideal, and this maximal ideal contains $\mathfrak m$, by the definition of  $\mathfrak m$.

*Note:* A Dedekind domain with a frinite number of maximal ideals is a P.I.D.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. So is this exercise in Neukirch book poorly worded? Have you got any ideas on how to fix it or is it just plainly wrong? Thank you so much. (I added the statement of the exercise at the end of my question)

Comment: I'll try to check. At the moment, I think it may be it is true if the Dedekind domain is not a P.I.D.